# Bundling and Minification automatically when building projects

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I can minify single file like scripts and stylesheets and can bundle them. Because of this, If I change any `css` and `js` file, each time I have to minify and bundle them manually. It makes me irritated. I want to automatically minifiy `js` and `css` files when the project builds.

I have searched for solutions online and its shows the use of external tools like `Gulp`. So please suggest a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Bundling does the minification automatically when in production. You do not need to do it yourself

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification